# FullCalendar: how to remove entries from 'Select Language' dropdown list?

Tags: 8

I use [Fullcalendar View](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar_view) to display some nodes:
[image] 
I'd like to restrict the content of 'Select Language' dropdown list to specific entries (let's say English, French and Finnish).

I couldn't find how to do that.
Is it in the module code, in the library?
Any help?